# Concurrency with GAE basic scaling in Node.js

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, concurrency, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-tasks

I'm trying to run long tasks (>10 min) by using Google Cloud Tasks with Google App Engine running node.js.

Goal is that other app would push hundreds of tasks to Cloud Tasks queue and each instance of Google App Engine would process those tasks one by one. I'm using so called **`basic_scaling`** option to allow tasks to run up to 24h (vs. 10 mins limit with `automatic_scaling`).

Currently it works but it seems one instance is processing more than one request at a time.

Is there any way to limit max concurrent requests per instance with "basic" scaling option?

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation, under [Establish Rate Limits](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-queues#rate) there are two flags you can use to configure your queue rate limit:

```
--max-dispatches-per-second=[DISPATCH_RATE]
--max-concurrent-dispatches=[MAX_RUNNING]
```

If you are trying to ensure only one task is in processing at a time, it seems like `--max-concurrent-dispatches` is your solution.

Comment: What if I set `max_instances: 3` in `basic_scaling` to have up to 3 instances running. And I set `--max-concurrent-dispatches=3` to accomplish processing Cloud Tasks by 3 instances, but only **one task per instance at a time**.
Unfortunately it looks like tasks send those concurrent 3 requests to one instance and other two instances are not created.
From the docs of GAE basic scaling I don't understand under what conditions it spins up additional instances. Do you?

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#max_concurrent_requests the default is 10, it sounds like you want App Engine to operate with concurrency of "1".

Comment: You are referring to to `automatic_scaling.max_concurrent_requests`, however my question was targeted to `basic_scaling`. Why I care about basic scaling is the timeout issue described above.

Comment: @cernuus - How did you figure out the solution to this problem? I'm in a very similar position.